# Duplicate tables and procedures in master database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, master-system-database

I've just discovered, that `master` database contains duplicates of some other databases' tables and stored procedures.

For example, I have a database `SomeDB` with table `justTable` in it. For some reason, a copy of this table is in `master` as well, but with no data.

How is it possible? I'm certain that when I was creating those tables and procedures I was using corresponding databases and not `master`. They are all present in those databases (as they should be), just with a copy in `master` as well.

I use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2014 with Redgate additions (source control and stuff).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you create the table with a script run through SSMS?

Is it possible that if you did you didn't include `USE [SomeDB]` at the top of the script and instead had the current DB set to master?

So doing this:

[image: Bad]

Instead of this:

[image: Good]

You can see *when* a specific table was created by looking at the system views, as in:

```
SELECT ObjectName = QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(o.name)
    , o.create_date
FROM sys.objects o
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE o.type_desc = 'USER_TABLE';
```

This may help you understand where/when those tables were created.

Results from the query:

[image]

If you really need to prove where these are coming from, you probably want to create a DDL trigger at the server level to capture events such as `CREATE TABLE` etc, however that is beyond the scope of this answer.  A Server-level DDL Trigger would allow you to capture all data-definition events for *future* events; i.e. it wouldn't help solve where these existing tables came from.

Comment: @retif Yes, this is the only thing that makes sense, especially if you can't reproduce the issue. If it were repeatable, I would have checked for a DDL trigger or a job that - for whatever reason - made a copy of every table you create.